# Can I throw my hands to spite my enemies?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk, multi-classing, barbarian

Here's an odd question a player brought up to me about D&D 4e. I was curious on your thoughts. Barbarians can take the feat Hurl Weapon:

> You can use any one-handed off-hand weapon as a heavy thrown weapon. Normal range for weapons you wield this way is 5 squares, and long range is 10 squares.

Monks treat unarmed attacks as one-handed off-hand attacks.

Could a multiclass barbarian/monk throw their fists (ki-blast)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This gives a new meaning to un*arm*ed attack, but doesn't seem particularly useful.**

First, the [unarmed strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=362):

> When you make a weapon attack such as a melee basic attack, you can use the monk unarmed strike, which is a weapon in the unarmed weapon group. This weapon has the off-hand weapon property and a +3 proficiency bonus, and it deals 1d8 damage. You must have a hand free to use your monk unarmed strike,

Hurl Weapon states:

> You can use any one-handed off-hand weapon as a heavy thrown weapon

Therefore, all a monk needs to do is amputate their hands, and they can indeed chuck them at an enemy as heavy thrown weapons. There is no provision for "ranged unarmed hands-less ki attacks" though. Perhaps the monk should invest in increasing her reach instead.

On a more serious note, however, there are no restrictions on [refluffing](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3013666) thrown shuriken (or what have you) to be "ki bolts" if it fits the character's style. Also appropriate would be a [transcendent ki focus](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3738) proficiency.

Comment: To be a full answer, perhaps this should include details of how a monk can amputate their own hands?

Comment: Perhaps the same way a barbarian can throw his brain?

Comment: Most I could think of is ripping off your own arm and beating someone to death with it/throwing it at them. Still begs the question of you you get it off, but you kind of need to keep at least one hand in order to throw one.

Comment: Hey. A monk could bite both her hands off, and spit them at her enemies. Wait, no. That'd be undignified.

Answer (score -1):

In the RAW yes. But after throwing it, they would have to go pick it up again as well.

The hand would literally be thrown, not some sort of Ki blast. If you wish, as the GM however, you can always house-rule it in and reward them for their creativity.

Comment: Is it possible to enchant fists with the returning property?

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to know that 4e doesn't do "returning" like 3.5 and PF. **Rules Compendium page 282:** *"Any magic light thrown or heavy thrown weapon [...] automatically returns to its wielder's hand after a ranged attack with the weapon is resolved."* While "wielder's hand" is an awkward phrase to interpret in this context, the notion of a "returning property" is meaningless in the 4e context.

Comment: @Nerdyfool returning should probably be a question, such that BESW can derive benefit from his *answer*.

Comment: Is a monk's hand magic though? Else it still wouldn't return.